# C++ macro defined using do while causing error

Tags: c++, macros

I have two pieces of code I need to make running. (No, I am not allowed to change either of them).

First piece defines a macro

```
#define MACRO do { /* stuff in multiple lines and do not return a value */ } while (0)
```

Second piece uses another macro in an `if` statement

```
if (ANOTHER_MACRO) { /* do some stuff */ }
```

I need to make `ANOTHER_MACRO` use `MACRO` and I am allowed to define `ANOTHER_MACRO`.

I thought an `inline` function would be the right way to do it, but neither by using macros nor by using `inline` functions I could get it work. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you need to do stuff inside the condition instead of just providing a condition?

Comment: Why are you even wasting time with macros ? This is C++, not C, and the year is 2015, not 1985 - use (inline) functions.

Comment: Try inline or lambda expressions...

Comment: Is that really the definition of `MACRO`? Also, I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: `MACRO` is definitely not meant to be used as a condition. Why do you want to stuff it in that `if` ? Can't you run it beforehand ?

Comment: @chris I had to edit the question. yes, I have to do stuff in condition

Comment: @PaulR these two are already defined and as I wrote, I am not permitted to change them. inline function would be a way to bind these two, but I didn't manage it. So any suggestion using inline function is also welcome

Comment: @Quentin I agree with you, but as I said, I am not allowed to change it and it is used this way.

Comment: Use a lambda expression defined by ANOTHER_MACRO (assuming you have at least a c++11 compiler)

Answer (score 1):

Just insert a function to call `MACRO` on one side and return a value on the other.

```
#define ANOTHER_MACRO theFunc()

bool theFunc() {
    MACRO;
    return /* something */;
}
```

Comment: I had tried this way as an inline function, but it complained about the syntax just like the macro did. A real function definition solves it, thank you

Comment: @lulijeta If you also want to know why what you tried didn't work, you need to add it to your question, along with the compiler error it generated.